# How can I compare two strings from both arrays and display a correct/wrong message?

Tags: php, html

Update: I am doing a quiz and I stored my questions into a 2D array while user's answers into an array. There will be a randomized 4 questions being displayed each time. However I keep getting the error message despite writing the correct answers...one of the PHP file is under validation file but both with the same file name. please excuse the messy CSS, will fixed after this can be solved, appreciate the help!

```
<?php 
$four_qn = array();  
$correct = $error = "";
$score = 0;
$four_qn = array();
$ansArray = array();
$qn_array = array(
        1 => array(
                'Question' => "In which novel of Roald Dahl, the character Willy Wonka can be found?", 
                'Answer'=> "charlie and the chocolate factory"
        ), 
        2 => array(      
                'Question' => "‘West Side Story,’ a musical is based on a tragedy by Shakespeare. Which tragedy is it?", 
                'Answer' =>"romeo and juliet"
        ), 
        3 => array(
                'Question' => "Who became the best-selling author in the 2000s in Britain?",
                'Answer' => "jk rowling"
        ),
        4 => array( 
                'Question' => "What is the name the novel by George Orwell where we find the character ‘Napoleon’?", 
                'Answer' => "animal farm"
        ),
        5 => array( 
                'Question' => "Tweedledum and Tweedledee are two characters of which Children’s book?",
                'Answer' => "alice in wonderland"
        ),
        6 => array( 
                'Question' => "Name the mega-selling writer who has written “Deception Point”?", 
                'Answer' => "dan brown"
        ), 
        7 => array(
                'Question' =>"‘A Brief History of Time’ is a famous book written in 1988. Who is its author?",
                'Answer' => "stephen hawking"
        ), 
        8 => array(
                'Question' => "Who ended his writing career with ‘The Last Tycoon’?", 
                'Answer' => "F scott fitzgerald"
        ),
        9 => array(
                'Question' => "What literary tale contains the phrase “fee, fie, fo, fum”?", 
                'Answer' => "jack and the beanstalk"
        ), 
        10 => array(  
                'Question' => "Theodor Geisel used what pen name when writing his children’s books?",
                'Answer' => "dr seuss")
    ); 

    //get four random elements
    function getRand($qn) {
        shuffle($qn); //randomize 
        $qn = array_slice($qn, 6); //slice the array to get 4 elements and store into new array 
        return $qn;
    }

     $four_qn = getRand($qn_array); 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            if (isset($_POST['ans'])) { 
                    $ansArray = $_POST['ans'];
                    if (is_array($ansArray)) {
                            foreach ($ansArray as $q => $ans) { //answers from user 
                                    foreach ($qn_array as $q => $correctAns)  //original answer 
                                            $ans = stripslashes($ans); 
                                            if (strlen($ans) > 0) {
                                                    if (strcasecmp($correctAns['Answer'], $ans)==0) {

                                                            $correct =  "You are right!" . "<br>";
                                                            $score += 5; 
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                            //$error = $_POST['error'];
                                                            $error =  "You are wrong.. " . "<br>";
                                                            $score -= 3; 
                                                    }
                                            } 
                                            else 
                                                    $emptyMsg = "You did not enter a value";
                            
                            }
                   
                    }
            }
    } 


?>
```

```css
<style>
    body {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;

    }
    
    .header {
        margin-left: 45%;
        padding: 15 15;
    }

    input {
        float:left;
        margin-left: -5%;
 
    }
    input[type="text"]
    {
        position: absolute; 
        left: 35%;
        width: 30%;
    }

    .correct {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 45%;
    }

    .error {
        margin-left: 45%;
    }
    .count {
        float:left;
        margin-left: 30%;
    }

    h3 {
        
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px 6px;
        vertical-align: top;
    
    } 

    .submit {
        margin-left: 45%;
    }


</style>
```

```html
<?php 
include_once('validation/lit.php');
?>

<body> 

    <!-- title --> 
<div class="header">Literature quiz</div>
    <br><br> 

    <form method="post" action="lit.php"> 
       &nbsp;
    <?php 
    $count = 1;
    while ($count < 5) {
            foreach ($four_qn as $qn => $value) { 
                    echo "<h3 class='count'>$count)</h3>" ; ?>
                <div class="questions">
                    <h3> <?php echo $value['Question'] ;
                    ?>
                    </h3> 
                </div>

                <div class="answers">
                    <?php 
                    echo '<input type="text" name="ans[]">' . "<br>"; ?>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $error ;?></span>
                    <span class="correct"><?php echo $correct ;?></span>
                <br>
                <?php 
                    $count++; ?>

                <span name="error" class="error" value="<?php echo $emptyMsg ;?>">
                <?php
            } 
    } ?>
                </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type= 'submit' name='submit' value="Check answers" class="submit">

    <?php 

?>
</form>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question really is how to compare two strings in php.
[This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) is how you do it.

Comment: I did the strcasecmp() function but somhow still not able to get what I wanted ://